# Manually remove route leave hook set via setRouteLeaveHook

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'd like to know how to manually remove the setRouteLeaveHook for a particular route. This [page](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md) says that I shouldn't need to do this in most cases manually but doesn't mention how I could do this if I needed to.

> You don't need to manually tear down the route leave hook in most cases. We automatically remove all attached route leave hooks after leaving the associated route.

The reason is probably best explained through example.

```
class Editor extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
    const { dispatch, dirty, route } = this.props;
    const { router } = this.context;
    router.setRouteLeaveHook(route, this.routerWillLeave.bind(this));
}

routerWillLeave(nextLocation){
  console.debug('routerWillLeaveCalled -> ', this.props);
  let { dirty, dispatch, resetForm } = this.props;
  const { router } = this.context;
  if (dirty) {
    let dialog = {
      id: Date.now(),
      showTitle: true,
      titleContent: 'Unsaved Changes',
      titleIcon: 'fa fa-warning',
      content: <span>You have <strong>unsaved</strong> changes! <strong>Discard</strong> them?</span>,
      type: 'confirm',
      handleCloseClick: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(closeDialog());
      },
      acceptBtn: {
        title: 'Okay',
        handler: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          resetForm();
          console.debug('handler dirty ->', dirty);
          dispatch(push(nextLocation));
          // dispatch(closeDialog());
        }
      },
      denyBtn: {
        title: 'Deny',
        handler: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          dispatch(closeDialog());
        }
      }
    }
    dispatch(addDialogWindow(dialog));
    dispatch(openDialog(false, (e) => dispatch(closeDialog()), false));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

}
```

The issue I'm having is in `acceptBtn`. After calling redux-forms `resetForm()` function the Editor component is not yet updated (with the new props, and I'm not sure why) which means that dirty is still set to true when `dispatch(push(nextLocation));` is called.

Heres what the flow looks like:

1. Link is clicked which results in a different route.
2. routerWillLeave is called for the first time. It dispatches some action which shows my dialog (which has two buttons accept and deny).
3. When acceptBtn is clicked for the first time what happens is that routeWillLeave is called again (since its still hooked). For some reason at this point even though `resetForm()` has been dispatched the component still hasnt updated which means `dirty == true` and the same block of code is executed again.
4. Clicking on acceptBtn a second time will now trigger routerWillLeave again but this time `dirty == false` and thus it returns true and the route changes as it should.

Here are the actions that have been dispatched after clicking `acceptBtn` the first time.

```
action @ 01:26:08.101 redux-form/RESET 
action @ 01:26:08.105 @@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD 
action @ 01:26:08.117 ADD_DIALOG_WINDOW 
action @ 01:26:08.127 OPEN_DIALOG
```

And this is after clicking it a second time.

```
action @ 01:26:02.235 ADD_DIALOG_WINDOW 
action @ 01:26:02.239 OPEN_DIALOG 
action @ 01:26:08.101 redux-form/RESET 
action @ 01:26:08.105 @@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD 
action @ 01:26:08.117 ADD_DIALOG_WINDOW 
action @ 01:26:08.127 OPEN_DIALOG 
action @ 01:43:10.358 redux-form/RESET 
action @ 01:43:10.363 @@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD 
action @ 01:43:10.372 @@router/LOCATION_CHANGE 
action @ 01:43:10.670 redux-form/DESTROY 
action @ 01:43:10.676 redux-form/DESTROY
```

As a result what I wanted to do was to remove the hook within acceptBtn's handler function. Is this possible/ok to do? Or is there something I'm doing wrong, or a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

To remove the setRouteLeaveHook hook.

```
let remove = router.setRouteLeaveHook(route, (nextLocation) => {
   remove()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was an issue with timing execution of the dispatch calls. Wrapping the location dispatch in a Timeout of 0 fixed the issue.

```
      acceptBtn: {
        title: 'Okay',
        handler: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          resetForm();
          // Wait for call stack to unwind and then execute
          // the following which will now have the updated values.
          setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(push(nextLocation));
            dispatch(closeDialog());
          }, 0);
        }
      },
```